# How to find how large Var[R] of a positive integer valued random variable can be given Ex[R]=2?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

If we are given the expectation of a positive integer-valued random variable how can we find the bound on variance?

Answer (score 2):

There is no bound: it can be arbitrarily large.  Consider $X$ which is $n$ with probability $1/(n-1)$ and $1$ otherwise.  Then $\mathbb E[X] = 2$, but $\mathbb E[X^2] = n+2$, so $\text{Var}(X) = n-2$.